# Error when displaying pdf: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, dopostback

I am trying to pull a pdf file out of SQL and display it to the user. I keep getting the following error:
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed.

My project is using asp.net to load a gridview that contains a linkbutton to the database record that contains the pdf.

When the user clicks the linkbutton, the pdf should be pulled from SQL and displayed using Response.BinaryWrite.

Here is my aspx code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ReturnedReports.aspx.cs" Inherits="PP.ApKPI.WEB.ReturnedReports" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeaderContent" runat="server">
    <h1>Reports</h1>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="ReportsUpdatePanel" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Panel ID="ReportsPanel" runat="server" Height="611px">
                <h2>
                    Reports
                </h2>
                <asp:Label ID="ReportsNotification" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Pharmacy: "></asp:Label>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="PharmaciesDropDownList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="PharmaciesDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <br />
                <br />
                <%--<asp:Button ID="NewReport" runat="server" Text="Add Data" OnClick="NewReport_Click" />--%>
                <asp:GridView ID="ListReportsGridView" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true"
                    GridLines="None" PageSize="10" CssClass="GridView" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                    EmptyDataText="No rows for selection." OnRowCommand="ListReportsGridView_RowCommand"
                    OnPageIndexChanging="ListReportsGridView_PageIndexChanging"
                    OnRowDataBound="ListReportsGridView_RowDataBound" 
                    EnablePersistedSelection="True"
                    DataKeyNames="FinDataID">
                    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="GridViewAltRow" />
                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="GridViewHeader" />
                    <RowStyle CssClass="GridViewItem" />
                    <PagerStyle CssClass="GridViewPager" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" ControlStyle-CssClass="Hidden" ItemStyle-CssClass="Hidden"
                            HeaderStyle-CssClass="Hidden" FooterStyle-CssClass="Hidden" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="FinDataID" HeaderText="FinDataID" ControlStyle-CssClass="Hidden" ItemStyle-CssClass="Hidden"
                            HeaderStyle-CssClass="Hidden" FooterStyle-CssClass="Hidden" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="PeriodStart" HeaderText="Period Start" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="PeriodEnd" HeaderText="Period End" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" />
<%--                        <asp:ButtonField DataTextField="FileName" HeaderText="Report" CommandName="ViewRpt" />--%>
                        <asp:TemplateField><ItemTemplate><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonViewRpt" Text='<%#Eval("FileName") %>' CommandName="ViewRpt" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>    
                        <asp:TemplateField Visible="false"><ItemTemplate></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
                <br />
            </asp:Panel>

    <asp:Panel ID="UploadPanel" runat="server" >
        <h2>Upload Report for
            <asp:Label ID="UPharmacyName" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </h2>

        <p>
            <table width="360px">
                <tr>
                    <td>Period Start:</td>
                    <td>Period End:</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="lblUPeriodStart" runat="server" Width="50px"></asp:Label></td>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="lblUPeriodEnd" runat="server" Width="50px"></asp:Label></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </p>
            Select File to Upload:
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UploadPanel2" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <%--<asp:FileUpload ID="UploadFile" runat="server" />--%>
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="UploadFile" runat="server" />
                    <p>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" 
                            Text="Upload" />
                        <asp:Button ID="btnCancelUpload" runat="server" OnClick="btnCancelUpload_Click" 
                            Text="Cancel" />
                </ContentTemplate>
<%--                <Triggers>
                    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpload" />
                </Triggers>--%>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </asp:Panel>

        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:Button ID="btnClickMe" runat="server" OnClick="btnClickMe_Click" Visible="false" />
    <p></p>
</asp:Content>
```

And here is the partial code behind:

```
private void ViewPdf()
{
    //Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    //Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + objFileData.FileName);
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.BinaryWrite(objFileData.Data);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

As you can see I've tried invisible buttons outside the UpdatePanel and I've experimented with PostBackTriggers to no avail. I can't get a PostBackTrigger to work because my linkbutton is not recognized from the UpdatePanel...

Any help would be appreciated! Let me know if any more code, details are required. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to resolve this (ok not me someone I work with)!

Removing the outer UpdatePanel (ReportsUpdatePanel) solved the issue. I don't fully understand how that resolved it but apparently it had something to do with synch and sending the http header out of order. If someone else wants to comment and clarify this please do!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

remove `asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger` for related grid () from asp and add following code (as per your code ) this is example only

1. during page load add below codes

   ScriptManager scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
   scriptManager.RegisterPostBackControl(this.ListReportsGridView);
2. after then using auto select button =true . if you don't need the button u can set display as  none in ur grid rowbound.

Comment: Please reformat your answer so that it is more clear and easier to read. Use the code block tags.